# Why are Notes being created when I import contacts & accounts using Import Wizard?

Tags: account, contact, notes, data-import-wizard

I have been uploading mass contacts and account records (as CSV files) to Salesforce using the Import Wizard. All seems to be going fine, apart when I look at the Notes & Attachments for each record, all the fields from my CSV file are listed as separate 'Notes'.

How do I prevent this from happening? It's taking up a lot of unnecessary storage in my user account.

I understand that any *unmatched* fields are saved as a note, but these are fields that have all been successfully matched during the upload.

Comment: Weird. Could you add just the first few lines of the csv to help reproduce the problem?